# Mysql Query Returning Incorrect TimeStamp

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp, subquery

I have a table that I am trying run reports on. Problem is that when the same `session_id` is used it only selects the first timestamp for all the records.

This is my result set :

```
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| session_id | anum      | first   | last    | counselor        | why           | start    | Time With Counselor | total    |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
|        215 | A00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | Christine McGraw | Appeal        | 00:02:20 | 00:00:04            | 00:02:24 |
|        216 | B00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | Dawn Lowe        | Loan Question | 00:00:05 | 00:00:03            | 00:00:08 |
|        217 | D00000000 | forthis | isatest | Cherie McMickle  | Loan Question | 00:02:08 | 00:00:02            | 00:02:10 |
|        218 | A00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | John Ivankovic   | Tap Question  | 00:00:42 | 00:00:01            | 00:00:43 |
|        218 | A00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | Christine McGraw | Tap Question  | 00:00:42 | 00:00:01            | 00:00:43 |
|        218 | A00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | Tootie           | Tap Question  | 00:00:42 | 00:00:01            | 00:00:43 |
|        218 | A00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | Front-Kiana      | Tap Question  | 00:00:42 | 00:00:01            | 00:00:43 |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

notice the `session_id` `218` has the same timestamp for all of the records.

I group by the Primary keys (`session_id`, `Counselor`) because each counselor can work on one session so the timestamp must be different for all.

This is my query :

```
SELECT   
session.session_id,   
session.anum,   
student.first,   
student.last,   
c.counselor, 
session.why, 
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMEDIFF(t.start, session.signintime)) as start,   
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMEDIFF(t.fin, t.start)) AS 'Time With Counselor',   
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMEDIFF(t.fin, session.signintime)) AS total  
FROM session  
INNER JOIN student
    ON student.anum = session.anum   
LEFT JOIN (SELECT support.session_id, support.starttime AS start, support.finishtime AS fin FROM support GROUP BY support.session_id, support.cid) AS t  
    ON t.session_id = session.session_id    
INNER JOIN (select support.session_id, support.cid, counselors.counselor FROM support INNER JOIN counselors ON counselors.cid = support.cid group by support.session_id, support.cid) AS c 
    ON c.session_id = session.session_id 
WHERE session.status = 3
GROUP BY c.session_id, c.cid;
```

Am I missing something simple here guys/gals?

Thanks,
-RaGe

Edit Number 1 :

```
mysql> SELECT * from support WHERE session_id = 218;
+------------+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| session_id | cid | starttime           | finishtime          | counselorcomments |
+------------+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|        218 |   1 | 2013-02-06 13:26:40 | 2013-02-06 13:26:41 |                   |
|        218 |   2 | 2013-02-06 13:26:45 | 2013-02-06 13:26:48 | done              |
|        218 |   5 | 2013-02-06 13:26:25 | 2013-02-06 13:26:28 | v                 |
|        218 |   8 | 2013-02-06 13:26:34 | 2013-02-06 13:26:36 |                   |
+------------+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit Number 2 :

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM session;
+------------+-----------+---------------+---------+---------------------+-----------------+--------+
| session_id | anum      | why           | aidyear | signintime          | studentcomments | status |
+------------+-----------+---------------+---------+---------------------+-----------------+--------+
|        215 | A00000000 | Appeal        | 12-13   | 2013-02-06 09:01:45 |                 |      3 |
|        216 | B00000000 | Loan Question | 12-13   | 2013-02-06 09:14:10 |                 |      3 |
|        217 | D00000000 | Loan Question | 12-13   | 2013-02-06 09:14:57 |                 |      3 |
|        218 | A00000000 | Tap Question  | 12-13   | 2013-02-06 13:25:58 |                 |      3 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+---------+---------------------+-----------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

One session has many support tickets if needed. also this is a picture [Of My schema](http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/7193/selection002x.png)

Edit Number 3 :

```
SELECT   
s.session_id,   
s.anum,   
st.first,   
st.last,   
c.counselor, 
s.why, 
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMEDIFF(sup.starttime, s.signintime)) as start,   
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMEDIFF(sup.finishtime, sup.starttime)) AS 'Time With Counselor',   
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMEDIFF(sup.finishtime, s.signintime)) AS total  
FROM session s 
INNER JOIN student st
    ON st.anum = s.anum 
INNER JOIN support sup
    ON s.session_id = sup.session_id
INNER JOIN counselors c
    ON sup.cid = c.cid
WHERE s.status = 3
ORDER BY s.session_id asc;

+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| session_id | anum      | first   | last    | counselor        | why           | start    | Time With Counselor | total    |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
|        215 | A00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | Christine McGraw | Appeal        | 00:02:20 | 00:00:04            | 00:02:24 |
|        216 | B00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | Dawn Lowe        | Loan Question | 00:00:05 | 00:00:03            | 00:00:08 |
|        217 | D00000000 | forthis | isatest | Cherie McMickle  | Loan Question | 00:02:08 | 00:00:02            | 00:02:10 |
|        218 | A00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | Tootie           | Tap Question  | 00:00:27 | 00:00:03            | 00:00:30 |
|        218 | A00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | Front-Kiana      | Tap Question  | 00:00:36 | 00:00:02            | 00:00:38 |
|        218 | A00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | John Ivankovic   | Tap Question  | 00:00:42 | 00:00:01            | 00:00:43 |
|        218 | A00000000 | rixhers | jdjdjdh | Christine McGraw | Tap Question  | 00:00:47 | 00:00:03            | 00:00:50 |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Could you post the results of the support table? Doing  SELECT * FROM support WHERE SessionID = 218

Comment: updated, if you need anything else please let me know

Comment: If you noticed, the select query that I am having a problem with is just using the first record the (session_id = 218 and cid = 1) and it is using that for all the records after

Comment: Sorry can you add a SELECT top 5 * FROM Session also?

Comment: Thanks for the schema, looking now

Comment: What are you supplying a `GROUP BY` to the outer query when you have no aggregate functions (`SUM(),COUNT(),MAX(),MIN(), etc`)? MySQL wiil allow columns in the `SELECT` list which are not also in the `GROUP BY`, but their results will be indeterminate.

Comment: If you remove that `GROUP BY`, I suspect you'll see a result closer to what you expect.

Comment: Because in this situation if I do not use the outer GROUP BY I get a really funky data set. I can edit the OP to show you how it would look without the group by

Comment: @RaGe10940 If you are getting weird data without it that points to some other problem. The `GROUP BY` isn't appropriate without aggregate functions. Sometimes a `DISTINCT` is helpful though...

Comment: @RaGe10940 I see you are using a similar pattern in the derived tables in the `FROM` clause - a group by on different cols than in the `SELECT`, which will return indeterminate results for those other columns.

Comment: Thanks for the words Michael. By any chance do you have any good reading materials on this kind of stuff? If you haven't noticed I'm still learning.

Comment: @RaGe10940 Are you getting a more correct result now? The best reading material would just be to look at as many questions tagged [sql] here on Stack Overflow as you can.  MySQL has unusual default behavior for aggregates and group by, so it is important to understand how it differs (and why it can give you crazy results)

Comment: Yes the correct result is in the original post - without a group by or sub-query if I may add -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this query removed all the "goodness" that made the query look like a hot beast and got her down to everything that you actually needed.  I suggest naming the columns something appropriate.

```
SELECT   
s.session_id,   
s.anum,   
st.first,   
st.last,   
c.counselor, 
s.why, 
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMEDIFF(sup.starttime, s.signintime)) as start,   
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMEDIFF(sup.finishtime, sup.starttime)) AS 'Time With Counselor',   
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMEDIFF(sup.finishtime, s.signintime)) AS total  
FROM session s 
INNER JOIN student st
    ON st.anum = s.anum 
INNER JOIN Support sup
    ON s.session_id = sup.session_id
INNER JOIN Counselors c
    ON sup.cid = c.cid
WHERE s.status = 3
```

Comment: Splendid, if I may pick your brain, how did you get to this query? This works perfectly!

Comment: When you provide the map it made more sense on what you were trying to get at. I disregarded the joins and approached the problem one table at a time.  I saw you wanted students, so that was an easy join 1=1 on what we needed.  The next potion you wanted to know the support tickets times, the only key between the two was session_id.  As you join these tables it might be helpful to just run a SELECT * and see your table widen, it may help you visualize how the joins are performing.

Comment: Haha - thanks, this is also going live at the community college financial aid office so it better be A++